# Attach noi/poi-clauses to a selbri in Lojban

Tags: lojban

In Lojban, what is the right way to attach restrictive and non-restrictive clauses to a *selbri*?

Consider the English example:

```
It is the fourth-most populous city in California, after Los Angeles, San Diego and San Jose."
```

The phrase "the fourth-most populous" is a restrictive clause for "is city" (selbri "tcadu"). The phrase "after ..." is a non-restrictive clause for "fourth-most" (selbri "vomoi").

A naive approach would be:

```
accidental="la sandi'egos ce'o la sandi'egos ce'o la sanjoses lidne"
determiner="vomoi noi ${accidental} fi le nilxa'ugri"
phrase="tcadu poi ${determiner} la kalifornos"
```

But it doesn't work: one can't attach noi/poi to a selbri.

My current approach is to compound selbri:

```
accidental = "la sandi'egos ce'o la sandi'egos ce'o la sanjoses lidne"
determiner = f"ke ka {accidental} ke'e vomoi fi le nilxa'ugri"
phrase = f"ko'a ke ka {determiner} ke'e tcadu la kalifornos"
```

It works, but the noi/poi distinction is lost.